# AngularJS directive factory only called once

Tags: angularjs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

We are migrating to Google Closure Compiler at the moment. We refactoring our old code base so its fits to this article: [A radical new approach to developing AngularJS apps](http://www.mircozeiss.com/a-radical-new-approach-to-developing-angularjs-apps/)

The directives should look like:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Directive = function(version) {
  this.version = version;
  this.link = this.link.bind(this);

  this.scope;
  this.elem;
  this.attrs;
};

/**
 * Version directive factory. Entry point and used in `module.directive`.
 */
Directive.factory = function(version) {
  var dir = new Directive(version);
  return {
    link: dir.link
  };
};

/**
 * Linking function.
 */
Directive.prototype.link = function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  this.scope = scope;
  this.elem = elem;
  this.attrs = attrs;
  this.elem.text(this.version.get());
};

angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('version', Directive.factory);
```

All works fine, until we use a directive multiple times on a site. `Directive.factory` will only be called once. So all directives on sites share the same Directive object. We dont get it, why this is happening.

Comment: Factories, services, values, etc. are all declared only once in the lifecycle of an angular app...You can make that "object" into, say, a service...and inject it into your directive...isn't that enough for what you want to achieve?

Comment: We want to use our directive as constructor. Iam not sure how a service will help us.

Comment: You mean that every 'version' directive on page should differ from others because it was defined with factory? This won't happen, it doesn't work this way.

Comment: I don't get the real purpose of that...I think your directive might fail since it cannot find a service/factory named `version`

Comment: @deostroll: The purpose of using a constructor here is more testability and maintability in huge code base.

Comment: @estus The link functions of every version directive should not share the same context (this). Do you have an idea how it can work?

Comment: The link is method/routine angular calls whenever there needs to be a directive rendered on the page...but its the same object that gets called everytime... http://plnkr.co/edit/logXtaq2pBRTqAxP8YHv?p=preview

Comment: Tangential note: `@expose` in the compiler is officially deprecated. You'll need to use quoted properties, `@export` and `@nocollapse` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[An Angular service is a singleton object created by a service factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide). And so [DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api) objects are, they are singleton arrays which are created from objects returned by [directive factory functions](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/compile.js#L858) (directives appear to be services under the hood). Once factory function (`Directive.factory` in your case) was called, its result is cached as `versionDirective` service instance.

Once you know how exactly Angular [treats `compile` and `link` functions](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/compile.js#L866), it may be possible by the trick like this:

```
Directive.factory = function(version) {
  return {
    compile: function () {
      var dir = new Directive(version);
      // by default there is no 'this' in link
      return angular.bind(dir, dir.link);
    }
  };
};
```

And I would recommend against it, unless you know what you're doing very well. It won't help testability, or maintability, or anything but will abuse the framework.

A 'radical new approach' may or may not be beneficial, but it certainly doesn't imply things like that.

Comment: So in short: Its possible to write controllers as constructors. Services, Factories and Directives should not be written as constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's how Angular was designed. They won't benefit from using constructors/classes. While 'service' service providers may (they use 'this' in constructor).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with writing Services, Factories and Directives as constructors - you just have to remember that they will only be instantiated once. Everything will use a globally shared instance.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth : Do you have an example for that? Especially for directives. I did not understand how i can access the element (from linking function) in other methods of the directive object, if all directives share the same context. For e.g. this.element will be overwritten

Comment: @tschiela It is about syntactic difference, `function () { this.controller = ...; this.link = ... }` vs `{ controller: ..., link: ... }` (and the latter is generally less verbose and more readable). The thing you're talking about is hacking, and it is not encouraged by Angular (primarily because it won't do anything good).

Answer (score 1):

I've altered your example to reflect the fact that the Directive constructor is a singleton that is shared.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Directive = function(version) {
  this.version = version;
};

/**
 * Version directive factory. Entry point and used in `module.directive`.
 */
Directive.factory = function(version) {
  return new Directive(version);
};

/**
 * Linking function.
 */
Directive.prototype.link = function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  // this refers to the Directive singleton - it's shared between
  // multiple invocations.
  elem.text(this.version.get());
};

angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('version', Directive.factory);
```

If you want the behavior you were originally aiming for, you can alter your link method to construct an object:

```
/**
 * Linking function.
 */
Directive.prototype.link = function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  // This will be created everytime the template is cloned
  var versionDirective = new VersionDirectiveLink(scope, elem, attrs);
  versionDirective.setText(this.version.get());
};
```

This latter variant creates an object everytime a template is cloned. You can support more advanced behaviors with constructors this way.

Comment: Note that 'this.version.get' refers to lexical this, which is undefined (or equals to window) in links. It may not be an issue for arrow-powered classes, but for es-five this smells trouble.That's one of the reasons why link function isn't the best place for OO attempts.